# Is there any way to set a particular video to portrait mode only: in iOS??

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to restrict a particular video to portrait mode only (device orientation).if yes, How?? I want to set a particular video to portrait mode, rest other videos would be rotate to both landscape and portrait.please help me with this as i am not getting any clear stuff from googling.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: I am still googling and didn't find anything useful